# Как создать динамический ассоциативный массив на java

Tags: java, массивы, список, динамические-массивы

Не получается создать динамический массив на java.
Что-то наподобие:

```
long[][][][][] beans = new long[2][2][2][2][2];

for (int i = 0; i < beans.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < beans[i].length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < beans[i][j].length; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < beans[i][j][k].length; l++) {
                beans[i][j][k][l] = new long[(int) (1.0 + 6.0 * Math.random())];
            }
        }
    }
}

Gson gson = new Gson();

System.out.println(gson.toJson(beans));
```

---

Пробую создать массив который изображен ниже, используя HashMap
На примере с `long[][][][][] beans = new long[2][2][2][2][2];`
Не получается создать функцию, чтобы можно было увеличивать массив в глубину, и не увеличивать кол-во циклов (Используя рекурсию)

```php
[
    //первый элемент
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'children' => [
            [
                'id' => 10,
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 100,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => 200,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'id' => 20,
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 100,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => 200,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],
    //второй элемент
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'children' => [
            [
                'id' => 10,
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 100,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => 200,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'id' => 20,
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'id' => 100,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'id' => 200,
                        'children' => [
                            [
                                'id' => 1000,
                            ],
                            [
                                'id' => 2000,
                            ],
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],
];
```

---

Обновления

```java
class Item {
    public int id;
    public HashMap<int, Item>[] children;
}

Map<int, Item> items = new HashMap<>();

function void build() {
    for(int i =0; i<rows; i++) {
        createItem()
    }
}

function Item createItem() {
    Item item = new Item();
    item.id = Math.Random(0,10000);

    return item;
}
```

Вот из этого мне нужно сделать динамически заполнять массив. Т.е. использовать рекурсию

Указать кол-во уровней массива, кол-во субэлементов children

Comment: То что Вы показали похоже на дерево. Поищите материалы как строятся деревья вообще и в Java в частности. Да HashMap может помочь в этом деле.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что выхотите сделать. Не понятно, что является ключом а что значением, напишите сигнатуру для метода add и я попробую вам помочь.

Comment: Я добавил информации, думаю это лучшее объяснение

Comment: я бы на вашем месте смотрел не в сторону коллекций в чистом виде, а в сторону создания своего класса, реализующего древовидную структуру. и уже имея такой класс, подумал бы к чему его приспособить. например, у той же коллекции...